# Obtain counts across multiple columns after conducting a join on each individual column

Tags: r

This is a 2-part question.

I have around 10 variables of interest in a dataset with 100+ variables. I also have a different dataset (a crosswalk) that I need to join *individually to each of the 10 columns*. My first question is whether or not there is an efficient way to conduct the merge. I am assuming I will need a for loop, but was unsure of how to approach it. I am attaching mock data below- note: the var_no_interest variables are once in which I do **not** want to merge or obtain frequencies on (including this in case subsetting the columns is going to occur).

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("AC", "AG", "VG", "HH", "AE"),
                 var2_no_interest = c("AF", "FF", NA, NA, NA),
                 var3 = c("AF", "EF", "TT", "ER", NA),
                 var4_no_interest = c("AA", "ER", "AF", "LL", "OP"),
                 var5 = c("HH", "LL", "TT", NA, NA))

crosswalk <- data.frame(Code = c("AG", "HH", "EF", "TT"),
                        Category = c("MBD1", "MBD2", "MBD3", "MBD4"))
```

My first question again is what is the most effective way to join the `crosswalk` categories to the vars individually? So it is merging the `crosswalk` to `var1`, then to `var3`, then to `var5`. End result would look something like this.

```
  var1 cat_1 var3 cat_3 var5 cat_5
1   AC  <NA>   AF  <NA>   HH  MBD2
2   AG  MBD1   EF  MBD3   LL  <NA>
3   VG  <NA>   TT  MBD4   TT  MBD4
4   HH  MBD2   ER  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
5   AE  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>
```

The second part to my question is how would I obtain counts across the 5 categories? End result again would look like this.

```
  Category Counts
1     MBD1      1
2     MBD2      2
3     MBD3      1
4     MBD4      2
```

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr package you can solve like this:

```
df_joined <- df %>% 
  left_join(crosswalk %>% rename(var1=Code,cat_1=Category),by="var1") %>% 
  left_join(crosswalk %>% rename(var3=Code,cat_3=Category),by="var3") %>% 
  left_join(crosswalk %>% rename(var5=Code,cat_5=Category),by="var5") %>% 
  select(var1,cat_1,var3,cat_3,var5,cat_5)
df_joined

df_counts <- df_joined %>%
  gather(variable,value) %>%
  filter(grepl("cat_",variable)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(Category=value) %>%
  summarise(Counts=n())
df_counts
```

Comment: Seems like a simple solution! Thanks for this.

Comment: Just updated df_counts to use gather from tidyr. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For your first question

```
df %>%
  select(!contains("no_interest")) %>% # select the columns that do not contain the "no_interest" in the names
  mutate(across(everything(),
    ~ with(crosswalk, setNames(Category, Code))[.x], # name `Code` with `Category` and index the `Code` entries by their names that are given from the selected columns
    .names = "cat_{.col}"
  ))
```

which gives

```
  var1 var3 var5 cat_var1 cat_var3 cat_var5
1   AC   AF   HH     <NA>     <NA>     MBD2
2   AG   EF   LL     MBD1     MBD3     <NA>
3   VG   TT   TT     <NA>     MBD4     MBD4
4   HH   ER <NA>     MBD2     <NA>     <NA>
5   AE <NA> <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

---

For you second question

```
with(crosswalk, setNames(Category, Code))[df %>%
  select(!contains("no_interest")) %>%
  unlist()] %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("Category", "Counts"))
```

which gives

```
  Category Counts
1     MBD1      1
2     MBD2      2
3     MBD3      1
4     MBD4      2
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Would you mind explaining what is happening in the mutate? I am unfamiliar with this notation and am struggling to parse out what it is doing...

Comment: @shollaback `%>%` is a pipe operator such that the result from the previous step can be taken as the input in the following steps. I also added some comments and hope it can help you understand the code easier.

Answer (score 2):

This dataset is quite untidy, with important data encoded in column names. And you're asking for it to be transformed into a similarly untidy format.
Something like "column 1 value", "column 1 category", "column 2 value", "column 2 category" etc. isn't that costly when you have only five columns and two types of columns, but if either of those numbers grows even a little, it quickly becomes difficult to use, slower than alternatives, and all round a pain in the neck.

Instead of doing that, this is how you would turn it into a tidy format:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_transform = parse_number) |>
  inner_join(crosswalk, by = c("value" = "Code")) # presumably, you only want the rows where there is a match, otherwise, use left_join()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   name value Category
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
1     5 HH    MBD2    
2     1 AG    MBD1    
3     3 EF    MBD3    
4     3 TT    MBD4    
5     5 TT    MBD4    
6     1 HH    MBD2
```

If row number encodes some information, then you can include that also, by including a row number column.

To answer the second part, just add `count(Category)` onto the end of the above data.